# "Добавить точку" в routePanel

Tags: route

На картах в routePanel есть кнопочка "Добавить точку".
По клику на которую добавляется точка в маршрут.
Как это реализовать?

[image: Добавить точку]

Answer (score 0):

В тех. поддержке ответили:
"В элементе управления routePanel нет возможности добавить дополнительные маршрутные точки, но Вы можете написать свой элемент управления, предоставляющий данную возможность. Всю необходимую информацию для этого можно найти на страницах документации"